# React native error when get data firebase firestore

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I can add data to firestore on firebase. But I can't get data from.

Does anyone can give me example and good configuration for?

Error:

> Could not invoke RNFirebaseFirestore.collectionGet null

[Image for error when try to get data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPqX2.jpg)

```js
Build.gradle on Project

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }

        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
}
```

Build.gradle on App

```js
dependencies {
    implementation(project(':react-native-firebase')){
        transitive = false
    }
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:15.0.0"
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Version i used :

```js
"dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^5.3.0",
    "react-native": "0.55.4",
    "react-native-firebase": "^4.3.8",
```

This is my code to get data

```js
firebase.firestore().collection("Product").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
   querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
   });
  });
```

Thanks in advance